# What is the sampling frequency of ADC in lpc1768?

Tags: adc, lpc

I was going through the user manual of lpc1768, particularly the ADC peripheral. It's written that it is a 12-bit ADC with 200kHz conversion rate. There is no mention of sampling frequency of the ADC. How do I know what is the sampling frequency? and I do know the difference between conversion rate and sampling frequency

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The LPC1768 has **one** 8-channel 12-bit ADC capable to perform a maximum conversion rate of 13 MHz / 65 clock cycles = 200 kHz.

This means the samplings are multiplexed among up to 8 input. 
The resulting maximum sample rate per input is distributed on the used inputs:

- 1 input only - max. 200 kHz per input
- 2 inputs - max. 100 kHz per input
- 3 inputs - max. 66.67 kHz per input
- etc.